# How to find template by url in magento?

Tags: php, magento

May be this is an stupid question, but I am really facing issue to find the template in magento

```
www.xyz.com/youtube_videos
```

I am new one in magento, can someone please let me know in which directory I should find this template. I will be appreciate. I have searched but could not found.

Comment: please provide version magento?

Comment: @Naumov I just came to know by using wappalyzer that this project is using magento. I even don't know how to check version

Comment: if < 2 you can enable `show template hints` in `system` menu, and view `web site` if > 2 I are now. Magento have layouts systems and page result this is many templates

Comment: in magento admin you can see copyright

Comment: p.s. you can get me link project I can help you detect version

Comment: @Naumov it is Magento 1

Comment: ok enable template hint how to I write up.